# Compute the divergence of an arbitrary vector with SymPy

Tags: python, math, vector, sympy

In the moment I'm trying to code a module which can differentiate arbitrary dimensions of a vector. To be precise, it actually is a divergence operator for n-dimensions vector. This is my code

```
from sympy import *
q = int(input("State your vector dimensions: "))
n = q+1 

def divergence(f):
"""
Divergence operator for n-dimensions vector
Please write the vector in form of an array
Please use en to indicate dimension
ie: [10*e1+5e*2, 5*e3-10*e2, 45*e3]
"""

    w = symbols ('e1:%d'%n)
    a0 = diff(f[0], w[0])
```

I need a code to make n-numbers of the *diff* functions (which I import from SymPy) automatically. So whenever I state my vector dimensions, this divergence module will give n-number *diff* functions and differentiate it respectively to its dimensions automatically. It should be something like this. 
Let's say my vector consists of 5 dimensions (which I set from the input). Then, I will write *f* as an array with len(f) = 5. My code should be automatically generated to something like this:

```
def divergence(f):
    w = symbols ('e1:%d'%n)
    a0 = diff(f[0], w[0])
    a1 = diff(f[1], w[1])
    a2 = diff(f[2], w[2])
    a3 = diff(f[3], w[3])
    a1 = diff(f[4], w[4])
    return a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5
```

And whenever I set a new input, the code will automatically change respectively to the input. How can I achieve this?

The reason why I write

```
w = symbols ('e1:%d'%n)
```

instead of `

```
w = symbols ('e0:%d'%n)
```

is just because it's really conventional to state dimensions of a vector from e1, not e0.

I'm actually really new to SymPy and never learnt about symbolic computing before. Do all NumPy basic properties are also in SymPy (such as array and cos)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function computing divergence needs two things: a list of vector components and a list of variables in which to differentiate them. Without a list of variables, the meaning of divergence is unclear: for example, given the vector `[t*s, t-s]` how is one to know whether the first component should be differentiated in t or in s?  With the input of [vector], [variables], the function would be this:

```
def divergence(f, x):
    return sum(fi.diff(xi) for fi, xi in zip(f, x))
```

which works like this

```
t, s = symbols('t s')
f = [t*s, t-s]
divergence(f, [t, s])   # s-1
```

Aside: SymPy and NumPy are very different libraries. SymPy does not have any of NumPy vectorization methods. When working with SymPy, you want to use lists or tuples, not NumPy arrays. SymPy does have mathematical functions like "cos" but they are its own functions, not NumPy's. SymPy functions work with SymPy objects and NumPy functions work with NumPy objects.